# laravel css style needs to be working currently not working

Tags: css, laravel

[o](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skjp8.png)

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjC0X.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skjp8.png)

My css file is not working on admin panel management page ?
Can you help me in learning new programming language Laravel ?
cheers

Comment: skip the `public` part, `asset()` will set the path to the public folder, should be `asset('css/style.css')`

Answer (score 0):

from the image you shared, the style.css is inside the css folder so do this:

Instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/style.css') }}">`

write `<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">`

or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">`